# How to make the Type in lamba expression be the type of derived class from a generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class EntityMapperBase<T>
{
    protected void Map(string columnName, Func<EntityMapperBase<T>, object> func)
    {
        _mappings.Add(columnName, func);
    }

    protected object GetValueForColumn(string columnName)
    {
       return _mapping[columnName](this);
    }
}

public class PersonMap: EntityMapperBase<PersonMap>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map(x => ((PersonMap)x).Name);           
    }
}
```

I would ideally not want to have to cast `x` to the `PersonMap` class.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Suppose `T` is `string`. You're accepting a `Func<string, object>`. Why would you expect to be able to call that by passing in a `Base<string>`? Perhaps your parameter should be `Func<Base<T>, object>`? What are you trying to achieve? This is a bit of an X-Y problem at the moment.

Comment: I'm trying to access the derived class's properties in the function. Like `Test(x => x.Name)`. x is going to be `Base<T>` and then need to cast x to T, trying to prevent that.

Comment: Maybe your method needs to be generic too? Unfortunately, as I said before, you haven't told us what you're actually trying to achieve, so we can't really help you.

Comment: Sorry I might have press the enter button before I was completing my thoughts, not sure if you get notified by edits?

Comment: That's still not really enough context. We don't know why `Base<T>` is generic at all, or what your derived classes are doing. Please edit the question to give a lot more information.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably this:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    public void Test(Func<Base<T>, object> func)
    {
        func(this);
    }
}
```

Or if you use T as a property inside your `Base` object:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    public T MyAwesomeProperty { get; private set; }

    public void Test(Func<T, object> func)
    {
        func(MyAwesomeProperty);
    }
}
```

`T` != `Base<T>`

Why use generics? You can add functions without the type and do the same you are trying to do..

```
public abstract class EntityMapperBase
{
    protected void Map(string columnName, Func<object> func)
    {
        _mappings.Add(columnName, func);
    }

    protected object GetValueForColumn(string columnName)
    {
       return _mapping[columnName]();
    }
}

public class PersonMap: EntityMapperBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map(() => this.Name);           
    }
}
```

Comment: added another answer!